# I want to build this project for android unity 2dbut it just shows this error i have no idea

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to build a project as a test for android in Unity 2d 2021 lts version. The build settings are these:
[image]
After the process finishes this is the popup error:
[image]
And this is the console error:
[image]
I don't have any idea because of I am new to this please explain what to do.

Answer (score 0):

When installing a Unity version you need specifically select the operating system modules for which you want to build.

So in your case select those for Android. And you can add these modules after installing the version.
[image]